# What’s the best way to deploy multiple lambda functions from a single github repo onto AWS?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-serverless

I have a single repository that hosts my lambda functions on github. I would like to be able to deploy the new versions whenever new logic is pushed to master.

I did a lot of reasearch and found a few different approaches, but nothing really clear. Would like to know what others feel would be the best way to go about this, and maybe some detail (if possible) into how that pipeline is setup.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this isn't exactly what you asked for but I use Serverless Framework (https://serverless.com) for deployment and I love it. I don't do my deployments when I push to my repo. Instead I push to my repo after I've deployed. I like this flow because a deployment can fail due to so many things and pushing to GitHub is much less likely to fail. I this way, I prevent pushing code that failed to deploy to my master branch.

I don't know if you're familiar with the framework but it is super simple. The website describes the simple steps to creating and deploy a function like this.

```
1     # Step 1. Install serverless globally
2     $ npm install serverless -g
3
4     # Step 2. Create a serverless function
5     $ serverless create --template hello-world
6 
7     # Step 3. deploy to cloud provider
8     $ serverless deploy
9
10   # Your function is deployed!
11   $ http://xyz.amazonaws.com/hello-world
```

There are also a number of plugins you can use to integrate easily with custom domains on APIGateway, prune older versions of lambda functions that might be filling up your limits, etc...

Overall, I've found it to be the easiest way to manage and deploy my lambdas. Hope it helps!

Comment: I have edited my answer after you posted yours. I think you deserve an upvote even though you never mentioned how to integrate it with a CI/CD pipeline (although it should be obvious if people can deploy something from the command line), so here it is :)

Comment: I was about to edit my answer to reflect yours lol. We were working on two sides of the same problem.

Comment: I hadn't known of serverless, but now incorporating it has helped simplify and automate so much of the logic! Thank you! 

Comment: Nowadays i would use AWS CDK. Not as complex as terraform but way more functionality than Serverless Framework.

Comment: @Marc I am not sure what you mean by "way more functionality" Serverless Framework can deploy pretty much anything you need. If its not described in the frameworks own configuration that abstracts away the underlying CloudFormation you can actually just use the raw CloudFormation to deploy what you need as well.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow. You can improve your question by reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

You can setup a CI/CD pipeline using [CircleCI with its GitHub integration](https://circleci.com/integrations/github/) (which is an online Service, so you don't need to maintain anything, like a Jenkins server, for example)

Upon every commit to your repository, a CircleCI build will be triggered. Once the build process is over, you can declare `sls deploy`, `sam deploy`, use Terraform or even create a script to upload the .zip file from your GitHub repo to an S3 Bucket and then, within your script, invoke the [create-function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/create-function.html) command. There's an example how to deploy Serverless applications using CircleCI along with the [Serverless Framework](https://serverless.com/) [here](https://circleci.com/blog/deploying-a-serverless-application/)

Other options include [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/), [AWS Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy) or even maintain your own CI/CD Server. The same logic applies to all of these tools though: commit -> build -> deploy (using one of the tools you've chosen).

**EDIT**: After @Matt's answer, it clicked that the OP never mentioned the Serverless Framework (I, somehow, thought he was already using it, so I pointed the OP to tutorials using the Serverless Framework already). I then decided to update my answer with a few other options for serverless deployment

Comment: Agreed with Thales. For anyone still looking for a way to build a CI/CD pipeline for Serverless monorepo apps with CircleCI, here is a step by step post - https://seed.run/blog/how-to-build-a-cicd-pipeline-for-serverless-apps-with-circleci

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're using AWS Lambda, you may want to consider CodePipeline to automate your release process. [SAM(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/serverless_app.html) may also be interesting.

Comment: Do you mean, to use CodePipeline for triggering AWS Lambda which will then update function code for all other lambdas? As far as I see, it's not supported to update function code/switch to new version from CodePipeline.

Comment: CodePipeline let's you model a release process as actions to perform. There isn't a direct action to do what you described, but you can add actions like CloudFormation, CodeBuild and even Lambda functions to update Lambda function code or version and switch to the new version.

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same problem. I wanted to manage 12 lambdas with 1 git repository. I solved it by introducing [travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/). **travis-ci** saved the time and really useful in many ways. We can check the logs whenever we want and you can share the logs to anyone by sharing the URL. The sample documentation of all steps can be found [here](https://medium.com/swlh/setup-ci-cd-pipeline-for-aws-lambda-using-github-travis-ci-9812c8ef7199). You can go through it.